# I want to have two foreign key for a model in djano. One of these foreign key must create when something special happens

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, foreign-keys

I want to have two foreign key for a model. One of these foreign key must create when something special happens. How can I write this and call it at a specific time? Can I write it as a function in model and call it in view when something special happens?

Comment: I don't know I asked my questions well or not!  Ask if you have any doubts!

Answer (score 0):

If this something special is when an specific object is manipulated then you can use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/), otherwise if you want to handle it yourself you can set `null=True, blank=True` so the database can set the field to null and then you can create that object in one of your views functions and assign it to the related object.

Comment: I did not know about Django signal before, I will try, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what would be the use case for multiple Foreign Keys but in the question

> One of these foreign key must create when something special happens

This looks like something that can be achieved using Django signals
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/

It's especially useful when you would like to create a new User or modify the database on a certain change in the database

Comment: I did not know about Django signal before, I will try, thank you